# Log file that `sudo last` accesses?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, logs

The bash command `last` (needs sudo) prints out logs, which contain information on when different users log in/out of the shell.

I have been looking for the file that stores this information, that `last` would access. I have checked `/var/log/system.log` and other files within `/var/log`.

I have looked everywhere on the internet as well, and cannot find the location.

I have, however, confirmed that the file is within `/var/log`, because when I did `rm -rf /var/log/`, `sudo last` showed empty output until the next time I logged in.

Which file is it? Thanks.

(I am using OS X Mavericks if it makes a difference.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`last` derives its output by examining the *.launchd.events.*.stats files in */private/var/log/com.apple.launchd*.

Removing the files usually restricts the `last` output to the last login after rebooting. Consequently some additional file/database/in-memory structure has to exist.

Removing the files doesn't work consistently.

The stats files in the respective user folders (e.g. com.apple.launchd.peruser.0 or com.apple.launchd.peruser.501) are irrelevant!

Comment: Hmm... do you know their format?

Comment: Shouldn't this be `/private/var/log/com.apple.xpc.launchd/`? Or has this changed more recently?

Comment: @thepiercingarrow Have a look at `utmpx.h` for a bunch of functions to access it. Or at `http://opensource.apple.com/source/adv_cmds/adv_cmds-163/last/last.c` directly :-)

Comment: @patrix: this is the source code of `last`. The guts are in the `libc`.

Answer (score 3):

The file (executable) in question is `/var/run/syslog`

If we execute `man last` we get

```
SEE ALSO
     lastcomm(1), utmpx(5), ac(8)
```

We can find `utmpx` in the `/var/run directory`  Utmpx is a user accounting database of **current** login information.  The key here is this statement found in the [`man` page for `utmpx`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/utmpx.5.html)

> Traditionally, separate files would be used to store the running log
>   of the logins and logouts (wtmpx),
>        and the last login of each user (lastlogx).  With the availability of the Apple system log facility
>        asl(3), these separate files can be replace with log entries, which are automatically generated when
>        utmpx entries are written.

So, `utmpx` is generating log entries to the OS X's syslog function.   Execute the following command:

`syslog | grep 'login\['`

And you will get a list of all login events since the OS was installed (truncated)

```
May 26 17:03:12 Allans-iMac login[5572] <Notice>: USER_PROCESS: 5572 ttys003
May 26 17:26:15 Allans-iMac login[5572] <Notice>: DEAD_PROCESS: 5572 ttys003
May 27 10:10:57 Allans-iMac login[5196] <Notice>: DEAD_PROCESS: 5196 ttys002
May 27 10:10:58 Allans-iMac login[4741] <Notice>: DEAD_PROCESS: 4741 ttys001
May 27 10:11:18 Allans-iMac login[6253] <Notice>: USER_PROCESS: 6253 ttys001
May 27 10:25:45 Allans-iMac login[6281] <Notice>: USER_PROCESS: 6281 ttys002
May 27 17:17:15 Allans-iMac login[6281] <Notice>: DEAD_PROCESS: 6281 ttys002
May 27 17:17:21 Allans-iMac login[6253] <Notice>: DEAD_PROCESS: 6253 ttys001
May 28 13:40:06 Allans-iMac login[7123] <Notice>: USER_PROCESS: 7123 ttys001
May 30 09:11:25 Allans-iMac login[1213] <Notice>: USER_PROCESS: 1213 ttys000
May 30 09:11:25 Allans-iMac login[1220] <Notice>: USER_PROCESS: 1220 ttys001
May 30 09:23:19 Allans-iMac login[1220] <Notice>: DEAD_PROCESS: 1220 ttys001
May 30 09:23:19 Allans-iMac login[1213] <Notice>: DEAD_PROCESS: 1213 ttys000
May 30 20:57:16 Allans-iMac login[1695] <Notice>: USER_PROCESS: 1695 ttys000
May 30 20:57:39 Allans-iMac login[1695] <Notice>: DEAD_PROCESS: 1695 ttys000
May 31 22:33:30 Allans-iMac login[2592] <Notice>: USER_PROCESS: 2592 ttys000
Jun  3 16:46:28 Allans-iMac login[2592] <Notice>: DEAD_PROCESS: 2592 ttys000
Jun  4 20:44:43 Allans-iMac login[1789] <Notice>: USER_PROCESS: 1789 ttys000
```

---

For additional user accounting info, we can use the command `ac`

Executing `man ac` gives us

```
    NAME
     ac -- display connect-time accounting

SYNOPSIS
     ac [-d] [-p] [-w file] [users ...]

DESCRIPTION
     A record of individual login and logout times are written to the system log by login(8) and launchd(8),
     respectively.  The program ac examines these records and writes the accumulated connect time (in deci-
     mal hours) for all logins to the standard output.
```

So, according to `man ac` login information is written to the system log.  Executing `ac` gives us "If no arguments are given, ac displays the total amount of login time for all active accounts on the
     system."

```
$ ac
total     2477.23
```

To break it out by user:

```
$ ac -p
testguy      0.04
_mbsetupuser     0.39
allan     2476.74
root         0.07
total     2477.24
```

Comment: While `system.log`does store login information, I am unsure whether it is accessed by `last`, because when deleting the file, the `last` output persists. Does the same thing happen on your computer?

Comment: It's not the `system.log` it's `syslog`

Comment: @Allan Sorry that was too harsh. I didn't see the syslog part because I didn't properly refresh your answer.

Comment: Regarding `_mbsetupuser` see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33391174/656912).

Answer (score 1):

`last` is using `/var/log/asl/*` files.

Firing within one `Terminal` window:

```
/usr/bin/sudo opensnoop
```

and in another one:

```
last
```

will show you this in detail.

If you want to read it from the source, here it is:

```
http://opensource.apple.com/release/os-x-1011/
```

download:

```
Libc-1081.1.3
```

extract this compressed tar file:

```
tar fjx Libc-1081.1.3.tar.gz
```

and read:

```
Libc-1081.1.3/gen/utmpx-darwin.c
```