# Last command source file

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, login, logs

Despite what I thought, there does not seem to be any concrete/modern answer on the net, so my question is: where does the `last` command get its information from? I have found the file before, but months ago, and I can not remember where it is. So what is the directory of the file where `last` keeps its log?

### EDIT

This is technically the same as [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/240687/log-file-that-sudo-last-accesses), except for one thing: "/private/var/log/com.apple.launchd" **DOES NOT EXIST** on my mac (perhaps it was pre-El Capitan-only) as proven by the fact that

```
ls /private/var/log | grep "com.apple.launchd"
```

returns nothing. *com.apple.xpc.launchd* does exist, but is empty. So please reopen the question, as something is different

Comment: In Yosemite, last entries can be found in /var/log/asl/BB......asl. These files are in binary format. Run the command `strings` on these files.

Comment: @patrix ok, well fd0's answer is correct and answers my question, but it isn't on [that question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/240687/log-file-that-sudo-last-accesses), so what can I do now? I would turn his comment into an answer but...

Comment: @fd0 the only thing is that these logs don't seem to show which user was responsible for the login

Comment: @fd0 Can you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: The linked question/answer is valid for OS X 10.9 Mavericks only (maybe earlier or newer ones too but that's untested)

Comment: @patrix - what version of OSX is the last.c file you point to in your comment on the other question

Comment: @Mark the latest available, but older versions are available on the same site. The key message is: don't try to parse whatever file the current OS is reading, use the functions in `utmpx.h` instead. I was thinking of writing an answer with this, but posting ObjC code probably isn't something a moderator on AD should do :-)

Comment: The point from that code is that the file read is in setutxent_wtmp(0); and I assume from comments is /var/run/utmpx

Comment: @patrix I can't fully answer DJpotato's question. I do know from reading the manual for `syslogd` that `utmp` entries time to live is approximately one year. These entries would be in a data store in some form of `BB.YEAR.MONTH.DAY.USER.GROUP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard) Apple has replaced the `utmp`/`wtmp` mechanism with the Apple logging system. See `man 5 utmpx` for details.  Here is a pertinent excerpt:

```
Traditionally, separate files would be used to store the running log of the logins
and logouts (wtmpx), and the last login of each user (lastlogx).  With the avail-
ability of the Apple system log facility asl(3), these separate files can be
replace with log entries, which are automatically generated when utmpx entries are
written.  The API to access the logins and logouts is described in
endutxent_wtmp(3) while the last login info is accessible with getlastlogx(3).
```

See `man asl` for the programatic interface to the log system.  Apple Syslog saves all its utmp/wtmp/lastlog-like information in /var/log/asl/*.

Comment: Is your answer specific to Sierrra or is it for El Capitan?

Comment: This answer should be pertinent from 10.6 (Snow Leopard) onwards.  I have not looked at the man pages for Sierra, but I would expect it to continue to be relevant.

Comment: @GregTarsa sorry for the lateness, turns out I haven't been getting stack exchange (and an inconvenient number of other things) for months. This, is perfect, fd0 gave the same answer in comments but didn't put it in answer form.